# Firebase indexOn doesnt work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

**My structure:**

```
privateChatsDetails
{
pushKey1{
     lastMessage
          {
          displayName(String)
          photoUrl(String)
          text(String)
          time(Long value)
          uid(String)
          }
     users
          {
          user1Uid
          {
          chat = true
          some other details..
          }
          user2Uid
          {
          chat = true
          some other details..
          }
         }
pushKey2
     lastMessage{...}
     users{...}
....
}
```

I'm reading all chats into Listview using

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("privateChatsDetails").orderByChild("users/" + mUid + "/chat").equalTo(true)
```

**Working perfect**, but not ordered well, I'm trying to order by lastMessage/time,

After reading the Index Your Data docs, and some Stackoverflow questions, I tried some rules, no succeeded.

**What I have already tried:**

```
  "rules": {   
     "$privateChatsDetails": {
      "lastMessage": {
        ".indexOn": ["time"]
       }
      }  
     }
```

**And:**

```
  "rules": {
    "privateChatsDetails": {
      ".indexOn": ["lastMessage/time"]
    }
  }
```

**And:**

```
  "rules": {
      "privateChatsDetails":{
    "$lastMessageTime": {
        ".indexOn": ["lastMessage/time"]
    }
   }
  }
```

**Any idea?** 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include how you actually listen/handle the items. That is likely where the problem stems from.

Comment: Well, I'm using firebase recycle adapter, the problem isn't there.

Comment: You're telling the database to order/filter by `chat`, so the results will be ordered by that. They won't be ordered by time. Firebase queries can only order/filter on a single property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Possibly you are misunderstanding the effect of `.indexOn`.  It does not order the result of a query.  It only makes queries more efficient.  You say "_I'm trying to order by lastMessage/time_".  You cannot do that using `.indexOn`.

Comment: So there isnt any why to do that? I have to make that order in my app?